# Bingmap location setting errors

Tags: javascript, mobile, visual-studio-2015, bing-maps

I am using

> single bing map key to show the geo locations of two different users

at two different location.

Where as sometimes, bingmap is showing wrongly as,

> one of the user is getting the location of other user's location as the geo location

(logic is not to display various user's locations together but geolocation of that specific user)

and I am unable to figure out the reason for this.

I am looking for response if the same faced by somebody else and how have they resolved?

Comment: Can you provide more information, it is not clear what you are asking here. o you have any code for us to look at to understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: @rbrundritt sorry to delayed response as I have been trying to fix the bug I mentioned. Code is simple, "navigate.geolocation.getgelocation" and then when that resolves to geo coordinates, passing them to bing map rest API. that is all. IT is at starting point of app hence no session storage. even if it is session storage, two devices distance apart can not have same session values.  I have made some changes to code and need to see if this fixes the problem.